# What does execl ("/bin/emacs", "/etc/fstab"); do?

Tags: c++, c, operating-system, fork, execl

for example:

```
int pid1 = fork();
printf("%s\n", "[1]");
int pid2 = fork();
printf("%s\n", "[2]");
if ((pid1 == 0) && (pid2 == 0)) {
    printf("%s\n", "[3]");
    execl("/bin/emacs", "/etc/fstab");
    int pid3 = fork();
    printf("%s\n", "[4]");
} else {
    printf("%s\n", "[5]");
}
```

What does the line actually do?

> The `execl` family of functions replaces the current process image with a new process image.

So this program starts, just lets run through the program:

It will fork the processes into 2 with the first fork an print:

```
[1]
[1]
```

Afterwards it forks again so you have 4 processes and a print:

```
[2]
[2]
[2]
[2]
```

A child process has `pid == 0`. There is one child process with `pid1` and one with `pid2` so there will be exactly:

```
[3]
```

And here comes the `execl`. What does it exactly do at this point?

Comment: main process: 2 forks, prints `[1] [2] [5]`, child process 1 (from main): 1 fork, prints `[1] [2] [5]`, child process 2 (from main): 0 forks, prints `[2] [5]`, child process 3 (from child process 1): 1 fork, prints `[2] [3]` then overlays process with another program. I.e. `pid3 = fork()` never gets executed and you'll never see `[4]`.

Comment: Wikipedia [exec (system call)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exec_(computing)): "... that runs an executable file in the context of an already existing process, replacing the previous executable", i.e. any code after `exec()` in the original program is _dead code_.

Comment: I recommend reading [Lions' Commentary on UNIX 6th Edition, with Source Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lions%27_Commentary_on_UNIX_6th_Edition,_with_Source_Code). There you can step-by-step follow what exec() does (in section 12-3, line 3020ff).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question drawn attention to forking new processes besides it had an intention to clarify how does the `execl` work. So, it is declared as:

```
int execl(const char *path, const char *arg, ...);
```

> where  is an unspecified pathname for the sh utility, file is the process image file, and for execvp(), where arg0, arg1, and so on correspond to the values passed to execvp() in argv[0], argv[1](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/exec.html), and so on.
>
> The arguments represented by arg0,... are pointers to null-terminated character strings. These strings shall constitute the argument list available to the new process image. The list is terminated by a null pointer. The argument arg0 should point to a filename string that is associated with the process being started by one of the exec functions.

(taken from [`execl` documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/exec.html))

So, that means you are missing some arguments. In this case, you should be using it like:

```
execl("/bin/emacs", "/bin/emacs", "/etc/fstab", (char*)NULL);
```

This call should start `emacs` editor with argument `/etc/fstab` - which means `emacs` editor will be opened (if installed) with content of `fstab` file located in `/etc/`.

Comment: You've misread your source. The execution is 'as if' what you said was specified.

Comment: The string /etc/fstab is an argument to emacs, not a program.